# get bitmap view's fragment without display

Tags: android, android-fragments, bitmap

As title of this question I want to get bitmap image of view fragment without display it on screen there are my codes

```
     public Bitmap getScreenShootViewPage(Context context,ViewGroup container){

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        mSliderMovieDetailPages = new ArrayList<SliderMovieDetailPages>();
        mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide,container,false);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager)mRootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
        mViewPager.setClipToPadding(false);
        mViewPager.setPageMargin((int) UtiliesFunctions.convertPixelsToDp(30, context));
        if(MainActivity.mHomeReponse!=null&&MainActivity.mHomeReponse.getRibbons().get(mCategoryPosition)!=null){
            for(int i=0;i<activity.mHomeReponse.getRibbons().get(mCategoryPosition).getItems().size();i++){
                mSliderMovieDetailPages.add(SliderMovieDetailPages.newInstance(activity.mHomeReponse.getRibbons().get(mCategoryPosition).getItems().get(i)));
            }

            mSliderMovieDetailAdapter = new SliderMovieDetailAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),mSliderMovieDetailPages);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mSliderMovieDetailAdapter);
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mItemPosition);
        }
       return UtiliesFunctions.loadBitmapFromView(mRootView);
    }
```

this is my loadBitmapFromView function

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {
            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            b.recycle();
            Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
            v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
            v.draw(c);
            return b;

    }
```

I dont know why function v.getMeasuredWidth() alway return 0 please correct me. Thank alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MeasuredWidth` is 0 because the View has not been measured yet, since it has not been shown yet (it could have a different size in different parents). Same with `MeasuredHeight`.
However, you can measure the view yourself. Basically you are emulating the size the parent would give, if it would have one / or it would be drawing.
Here are some examples:

Parent forces 100px width and height

```
int widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(100, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);   
int heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(100, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
```

Parent allows any height:

```
int widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);   
int heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
```

Parent allows it's own width, the height should be calculated by the view itself (useful if you have a TextView for example, because then the height could change depending on the width):

```
int widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parentView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);   
int heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
```

So if you got your width and height measure spec, then you can measure the view, in your case by running:

```
v.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
```

After running this, `v.getMeasuredWidth()` and `v.getMeasuredHeight()` should return the expected values.

Comment: it work correct when v.getMesureWidth() return 100,  but function loadBitmapFromView(View v) return blank bitmap , it have nothing. please help me again, tks

Comment: Do not recycle the bitmap after creating it (remove the recyle line), that should fix it.

Comment: it's still not fixed when I remove recycle bitmap

Answer (score 0):

The reason maybe you call the code too early and view still not size.

You could try it by override `onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)`  medthod

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to convert view into bitmap.You have to call view.measure otherwise getMeasuredwidth() will return 0.

```
 public Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
    view.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    Drawable drawable = view.getBackground();
    if (drawable != null)
        drawable.draw(canvas);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return returnedBitmap;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I tried it and view.getMeasuredWidth() still return 0 and it say "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0", what I shoud do, thanks !